# Avoiding Boundaries `if` Cases When Filtering Image Matrix

Tags: performance, image, matrix, matlab

I have the following MATLAB Code which I want to optimize.
It's related to an image matrix (2D) which I want to filter.
Though it is MATLAB code, the same problem would arise in C code.

The problem is that I'm trying to access neighbors of the pixel which might cause problems at the boundaries of the image matrix.

```
vWeightsCoeff = zeros((2 * numRows * numCols), 1);

weightsIdx = -3;

% Filteration
for iColIdx = 1:numCols
    for iRowIdx = 1:numRows
        if(mod((iRowIdx + iColIdx), 2) == 0)
            continue;
        end

        weightsIdx = weightsIdx + 4;

        refPixel = mOutputImage(iRowIdx, iColIdx);

        if(iRowIdx < numRows)
            relPixel1 = mOutputImage((iRowIdx + 1), iColIdx);
            relWeight1 = vRangeTable(round((refPixel - relPixel1) * RANGE_RESOLUTION) + RANGE_CENTER_IDX);
        else
            relPixel1 = 0;
            relWeight1 = 0;
        end

        if(iRowIdx > 1)
            relPixel2 = mOutputImage((iRowIdx - 1), iColIdx);
            relWeight2 = vRangeTable(round((refPixel - relPixel2) * RANGE_RESOLUTION) + RANGE_CENTER_IDX);
        else
            relPixel2 = 0;
            relWeight2 = 0;
        end

        if(iColIdx < numCols)
            relPixel3 = mOutputImage(iRowIdx, (iColIdx + 1));
            relWeight3 = vRangeTable(round((refPixel - relPixel3) * RANGE_RESOLUTION) + RANGE_CENTER_IDX);
        else
            relPixel3 = 0;
            relWeight3 = 0;
        end

        if(iColIdx > 1)
            relPixel4 = mOutputImage(iRowIdx, (iColIdx - 1));
            relWeight4 = vRangeTable(round((refPixel - relPixel4) * RANGE_RESOLUTION) + RANGE_CENTER_IDX);
        else
            relPixel4 = 0;
            relWeight4 = 0;
        end

        weightsNormalizationFactor = PREDICT_NORMALIZATION_FACTOR / (relWeight1 + relWeight2 + relWeight3 + relWeight4);

        relWeight1 = relWeight1 * weightsNormalizationFactor;
        relWeight2 = relWeight2 * weightsNormalizationFactor;
        relWeight3 = relWeight3 * weightsNormalizationFactor;
        relWeight4 = relWeight4 * weightsNormalizationFactor;

        mOutputImage(iRowIdx, iColIdx) = mOutputImage(iRowIdx, iColIdx) - ((relWeight1 * relPixel1) + (relWeight2 * relPixel2) + (relWeight3 * relPixel3)+ (relWeight4 * relPixel4));

        vWeightsCoeff(weightsIdx:(weightsIdx + 3)) = [relWeight1; relWeight2; relWeight3; relWeight4];

    end
end
```

Just to clarify the variables:

- `mOutputImage` is the image matrix.
- `numCols` and `numRows` are the matrix dimensions.
- `vWeightsCoeff` is the vector of the weights.

Since each pixel is related to 4 others yet working only on half the pixels its size is 2 times the number of pixels.

Now, the questions are:

1. Can I do something smart to go over the same pixels yet skip the first `if` which works like dividing the pixels as in chess board (White Black Board)?
2. Can I do something to avoid the `if` which secures I'm not stepping out of boundaries and yet go through the same pixels?

If someone comes which a completely different arrangement I will be open for that as well.

Comment: Why are you doing the `if(mod((iRowIdx + iColIdx), 2) == 0)` near the top?  Is that part of the filter?  Could you describe the filter in words?

Comment: @brechmos, The reason is simple. Think on the matrix as a chessboard, each entry is either white or black. Now, I want to work only on the black / white. This `if` separates white form black (Or the other way). Thank You.

Comment: What are `RANGE_RESOLUTION` and `PREDICT_NORMALIZATION_FACTOR `? The code doesn't work without the two.

Answer (score 2):

## visiting black chess board squares

You might do a mod2 pre-calculation of `mod(iRowIdx + iColIdx, 2)` by creating a chess board boolean matrix before the loop, using matrix operations.

But much better would be to step `iColIdx` by 2. And have `iRowIdx` start at 1 or 2 as appropriate, and then step it by 2.

## boundary checking

Your matrix now is C x R. Simply allocate a (C+2) x (R+2) matrix, so you have zeros running along all four sides. Then iterate over just the middle, rather than over the whole matrix as you are now. So `iColIdx` for example would start at 2 and stop one short of the end.

Doing this will delete a great many `if`s, to give you Version2 of the code. You might even find that puts you in a position to produce Version3, which takes advantage of matrix operations instead of scalar operations, pushing much of the looping work down into matlab primitives, which would be faster.

## style

It would have been helpful to see the method signature, but your English description that `mOutputImage` is the only return value worked well enough.

Typo: % Filteration

It would be natural to express the normalization e.g. like this:

```
    relWeight4 *= weightsNormalizationFactor;
```

Leave a blank after `if`, please.

The extra parentheses in `mod` and places like this:

```
        relPixel1 = mOutputImage((iRowIdx + 1), iColIdx);
```

are a little odd, you could safely elide them.